# Removing index.php from URL laravel 5.4 when virtual hosts points to public folder

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2

There are countless posts here and elsewhere requesting help in taking out the public/ and index.php from a fresh laravel install on a live server. So many in fact that I'm a little embarrassed to ask this. However, Given that there is more than one way to skin a cat, I feel that the many different solutions can sometimes conflict with each other and cause more headaches.

I have taken out the "public" in the url from a recently launched laravel site by pointing the virtualhost domainname.com.conf to the public folder.

This however causes the need to put index.php after the domain in all requests or else the page doesn't work correctly.

When I do put index.php into the urls manually, some of the images can't be loaded since they don't have this hardcoded.

Furthermore, if I point the virtual hosts addresses directly to public/index.php, the site works but after about 10 minutes it stops working and nothing on the site will load, css, js images. It all stops. I assume this has somemthing to do with laravel view caches but clearing them doens't change any thing.

At this point I'm at a loss. I've put +8 hours into this off the clock and  am getting pretty desperate.

This is my htaccess folder in public(no htaccess in laravel root is needed?)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

This is the same setup I've used for other domains & laravel live sites with success. For some reason the index.php simply won't go away using anyone's solutions.

Any help? Have I been staring at the same htaccess/virtualhost files for too long?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have the DirectoryIndex properly set.

Check your configuration, in my case I got it on dir.conf file:

file: /etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf

DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm

Comment: My dir.conf looks identical to yours.

Comment: is the .conf file present in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ directory?

Comment: Yes, it's there too.